# List all Oracle procedures/functions (including in packages)

Tags: oracle, metadata

I want to list all procedures/functions in an Oracle server, including procedures/functions in packages. Am I doing it right?

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN up.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE' THEN up.PROCEDURE_NAME ELSE up.OBJECT_NAME END AS name,
CASE WHEN up.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE' THEN up.OBJECT_NAME ELSE NULL END AS package
FROM USER_PROCEDURES up
LEFT JOIN USER_IDENTIFIERS ui ON up.PROCEDURE_NAME = ui.NAME
WHERE up.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' OR ui.TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';

SELECT
CASE WHEN up.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE' THEN up.PROCEDURE_NAME ELSE up.OBJECT_NAME END AS name,
CASE WHEN up.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE' THEN up.OBJECT_NAME ELSE NULL END AS package
FROM USER_PROCEDURES up
LEFT JOIN USER_IDENTIFIERS ui ON up.PROCEDURE_NAME = ui.NAME
WHERE up.OBJECT_TYPE = 'FUNCTION' OR ui.TYPE = 'FUNCTION';
```

Comment: Did you get the results you expected?

Comment: Yes the result is correct, but i am not sure with the "USER_IDENTIFIERS" table. Is there another table to get the object type of a packagemember?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use user_identifiers, this view is not populated with default compiler settings. You can remove that join and view from your queries. A better view to use is user|all_arguments which lists procedures including arguments and data types etc.

Answer (score -3):

Try looking at the `dba_procedures` view.

Comment: You may want to add detail to your answer.  One-sentence answers are rarely much help.